# How to use product automaton and intermediate state to prove existence of regular language?

Tags: proof-explanation, automata, regular-language

> Let $L$ be a regular language over alphabet $\Sigma$.
>
> Let $\frac{1}{2}L$ be the following language: $\{w\in\Sigma^* \mid \exists y\in \Sigma^*: |y|=|w|, wy\in L \}$. For example if $L=\{\epsilon, aba, aaba, babb\}$ then $\frac{1}{2}L=\{\epsilon, aa,ba\}$. Prove that $\frac{1}{2}L$ is a regular language.

An example of proof that I saw uses definition of product automaton:

Because $L$ is a regular language a DFA exists $A=\big( \Sigma, Q,q_0, F,\delta \big)$ which receives $L$. Let $p\in Q$ and we can define a language $L_p$:
$$
L_p=\bigl\{ w\in \Sigma^*\mid \exists y\in \Sigma^*:\delta(q_0,w)=p, \delta(p,y)\in F  \bigr\}
$$
We can define a finite automaton which receives $L_p$:
$$
A_p=\bigl(\Sigma, Q\times Q, (q_0,p), \{p\} \times F, \delta_p  \bigr)
$$
Let us define $\delta_p$ for all $q_1, q_2 \in Q$, $\sigma\in \Sigma$:
$$
\delta_p((q_1, q_2), \sigma) = \bigl\{ (\delta(q_1, \sigma), \delta(q_2, \sigma')) \mid \sigma'\in \Sigma \bigr\}
$$
Therefore:
$$
\frac{1}{2}L=\bigcup_{p\in Q} L_p
$$
and because regular languages are closed under finite union then $\frac{1}{2}L$ is a regular language.

---

I understand that $p$ is some kind of an intermediate state between two halves of a word in $L$. I understand that the set of accepting states $\{p\}\times F$ means that we take some intermediate state $p$ with an accepting state in $L$ and for this there must be a total of $Q\times Q$ available states.

I don't understand why in $\bigl\{ (\delta(q_1, \sigma), \delta(q_2, \sigma')) \mid \sigma'\in \Sigma \bigr\}$ we need to use $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$. For example, if there's a word $aaaa$ ($aa\in \frac{1}{2}L$) in $L$ then $\sigma=a$ and $\sigma'=a$ so why do they need to be different.

Also I don't understand why we need this union: $
\frac{1}{2}L=\bigcup_{p\in Q} L_p$. Are there many different languages $L_p$? Didn't we define a single one?

Comment: This proof is just wrong. We clearly don't have : $\frac{1}{2}L = \cup_{p \in Q} L_p$ since $L_p$ can be essentially defined as : "all words such that there is path from $q_0$ to $p$ that can be encode with this word". If there there is no word that allows from $p$ to go on a final state then $L_p = \emptyset$. With this mind the union is not equal to $\frac{1}{2}L$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. There is a missing condition in the definion of $L_p$, which should be
$$
L_p = \bigl\{ w\in \Sigma^*\mid \exists y\in \Sigma^*,\ |y| = |w|,\ \delta(q_0,w)=p \text{ and } \delta(p,y)\in F  \bigr\}
$$
The formula
$$
\frac{1}{2}L=\bigcup_{p\in Q} L_p
$$
is now correct. Do you understand the other steps?